# Direct child CSS selector issue

Tags: css, css-selectors

Please consider the following HTML :

```
<div class="mytest">
    <ul>
        <li>Parent 1</li>
        <li>Parent 2
            <ul>
                <li>Child 1</li>
                <li>Child 2</li>
                <li>Child 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Parent 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to put a border around the "parent" `li` only, and I was convinced this CSS would do the trick :

```
.mytest > ul li {border : 1px solid #000;}
```

I read this selctor as : "select `li` which are children of a `ul` which is a direct children of a element with class `mytest`". But if I use that, the "child" `li`'s also get the border. [cfr this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/np67w89x/). Can someone explain why please ? I see no reason and I'm probably missing something important here cause I'm sure I already used this selector sucessfully for the same purpose before...

Comment: correct approach but all `li` below it are descendants.. you need to specify direct children for the `li` as well. So `.mytest > ul > li`

Comment: My fault was the wording. I shouldn't have spoken of "child", but "descendant", and in that case it is indeed obvious why it works like that... at some point it must have been obvious to me as I used that already to avoid styling nested li's , but I guess I must be too tired or so. Anyway, that was a stupid question but hopefully it can help somedy in the future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add direct child selector between `<ul>` and `<li>` like so:

```
.mytest > ul > li {border : 1px solid #000;}
```

With your code, you targeted all `<li>` in `<ul>` elements directly child of .mytest

Comment: I still don't understand... Your last sentence is exactly how I see it. My "child" li's are descendants of a UL which is not a direct child (but a grandchild) of `.mytest` , so I don't understand why they're targetted... but maybe I'm just misinterpreting the selector I use...

Comment: All of your <li> is wrapped in direct child <ul>.

Comment: ooooooh, ok I understand it, I was indeed misinterpreting the selector... I was reading `select li which are children of a ul which is a direct children of a element with class mytest` whereas I should read it `select li which are DESCENDANTS (at any level) of a ul which is a direct children of a element with class mytest`. stupid me :-) I'll validate this answer for the explanation...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.mytest > ul > li {border : 1px solid #000;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `>` before `li` like this **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/np67w89x/1/)**

```
.mytest > ul > li {border : 1px solid #000;}
```

Then only it will be considered as direct children of ul and the style will be applied only for that `li`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your selector, as it currently stands, selects the lists that are immediate children of your parent div and *all* descendant items of that list.

To have it select only those list items that are direct descendants if the list, you must add another child selector, like so:

```
.mytest>ul>li
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct child selector selects the immediate child that follows the parent so your code would go like this -

.mytest is the parent and its direct child is ul and ul direct children are li

**.mytext > ul > li {border : 1px solid #000;}**

is the correct format, also if you want to add only to the first direct child you could do like

**.mytest > ul > li:first-child {border : 1px solid #000;}**